# Does it make sense to use wordpress nonces for not-logged-in users for security reasons?

Tags: wordpress, nonce

I was reading the following article: https://konstantin.blog/2012/nonces-on-the-front-end-is-a-bad-idea/ which raises some questions. In the comments it's told that:

> One of the Automatticians at the VIP Developer Workshop told me that I should always (always) use a security nonce for ajax requests, even for not-logged-in users and requests that do not result in database or filesystem modification.

My theme uses an ajax modal login / registration form in the frontend, where a nonce verification is implemented for the registration process - but not for the login one.
Does that really make sense?

Even wordpress does not use nonces for login / registration in wp-login.php.
Woocommerce on the other hand does use nonces in the login / registration forms.
This is really confusing - what is the best practice - the wordpress- or the woocommerce way?
From a security point of view, does it make sense at all to use nonces for not-logged-in users in the login / registration process?

Answer (score -1):

A nonce is an "anti cross site request forgery token". It makes sure that a malicious site can't create a form or link to an action on your site that would trick a user into doing something they didn't intend.

The simplest form of this is a random malicious site creating a form that posts to your site's logout page. If a user submits that form (or the malicious site has JS doing so), then they're logged out. Harmful? Maybe not, at most annoying.

This goes for all actions. A nonce prevents this, because the other site wouldn't know what nonce to include in its form.

If you have some kind of lockout process, a malicious site could lock out known users by having other users post wrong credentials.

So yeah, a nonce should be used for actions that can be from anything to annoying to destructive. Do note that a CAPTCHA practically functions as a nonce.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question. Of course nonces in general make sense. What I want to know is if it makes sense to use them for not-logged-in users. Specially in login / registration forms: Should they be used, like it's done in woocommerce or not, like wordpress does it in wp-login.php?

Comment: It depends on what kind of actions not logged in users can perform and whether you want them to be susceptible to third parties making them do so. Do you not want other sites to be able to post to your registration form? Then put a nonce on it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Of course, I do not want other sites to be able to post to my login / registration form. I do not understand why wordpress does not use nonces in login / registration and comment form. Don't they care about other sites being able to post to these forms, then?

Comment: WordPress isn't really the example for doing things right.